# Not able to see report data in lightning community

Tags: lightning-community

I am logged in as Customer community plus user and navigating to report but getting below error.

Report is on case object and does not include any other object. It is built on standard case report type.I have added run reports,edit my reports,report builder permissions through permission set. OWD for case object for internal and external users are Public Read/Write. Profile has read/write to case fields.[image]

Comment: Did you check this article?                                   
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000325371&type=1&mode=1

Comment: Yes, OWD for case object is Public for both internal and external but still report is not visible to community users.

Comment: Please edit your post to include more details - does the report include other objects?  Have you set Read permissions on the Case object?

Comment: @DavidCheng I have added those details in question now.

Comment: @devforce the report type may not include other object but can you check if there is any column or filter in the case report that is referring to a formula, lookup or master detail field on another object ? if yes, ensure that community user profile has access to that related object